# How can I debug firewalld on CentOS 7 stopping running unexpectedly?

Tags: centos7, firewalld, systemctl

I have a brand new CentOS 7 server and am just performing the initial setup.

I have started firewalld with

```
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
```

both commands appeared to run successfully

> Created symlink from
> /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1.service to
> /usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service.
> Created symlink from
> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/firewalld.service to
> /usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service.

and the systemctl status command shows

> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled;
> vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: active (running) since WHENEVER

however, all morning there have been moments when checking in with systemctl status shows

> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service;
> **disabled**; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: **inactive** (dead)

I could understand the service having crashed, for example, but can anyone help me debug how it is being both stopped and disabled at arbitrary intervals?

Comment: Is this a physical server, VPS, ?

Comment: @Bert - It's a VPS

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of VPS or what company it's from? Some do not allow you access to run a firewall. I would open a ticket with them as it's difficult to troubleshoot an unknown VPS.

Comment: @Bert - you were correct, it was the host disabling firewalls. Thanks for the suggestion. I would've wasted a lot of time on that otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone else suffering a similar problem, this was a case where the hosting provider automatically disabled any user attempts to set up firewalls on the VM.

As per [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052100/how-can-i-debug-firewalld-on-centos-7-stopping-running-unexpectedly?noredirect=1#comment1370371_1052100), the solution was simply to open a support request with the host.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation yet to post a comment, but that was the idea.

Did you take a look at the firewalld logs ? I believe they are located in `/var/log/firewalld`.

If you don't find useful information in here, you could try to increase debug of the service by editing the `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld` file:

```
 FIREWALLD_ARGS=--debug=10
```

This was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53099017).